# IndexError and dictionary

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm on a cryptography program, and I need to run through several lists to achieve my goal. I encounter here an IndexError list index out of range but can't figure out why

```
def chiffrement2(texte,dico):
    Listeindices = []
    lettre = ''
    i = 0
    Indices = []
    taille2 = len(texte)
    for i in range(taille2):
        lettre = texte[i]
        Listeindices.append(i) = dico[lettre]         <- Error is here.
        Indices[i] = random.choice(Listeindices[i])
    return Indices
```

"texte" is a string and "dico" a dictionary, keys are letters from A to Z, and their values are the positions of each letter in the string. (If the letter appears two times, its two positions will be stored in a list.)

Dictionary is like : dico = {"A":[1,9],"B":["12,19].... "Z":[78, 108]}

Comment: We don't know what is the content of 'dico'. Moreover you don't show us the error. What line is it about.

Comment: `Listeindices.append(i) = dico[lettre]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Oh, would you mind to explain me how to write it properly ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `Listeindices.insert(i, dico[lettre])`

Comment: It worked, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

One: `Listeindices.append(i) = dico[lettre]` is mixing up two things. Try `Listeindices.append(dico[lettre])`

Two: `Indices[i] = random.choice(Listeindices[i])`: Indices[i] does not exist! Don't you mean `Indices.append(...)` instead of `Indices[i] = ...`?

Comment: Well I wanted to store one random position taken from the dictionary in Indices. The final goal is to encrypt a text.

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary rather than a list then!

Comment: Nope, I need a list, but thank you too, you comment helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
def chiffrement2(texte,dico):
    Listeindices = []
    lettre = ''
    i = 0
    Indices = []
    taille2 = len(texte)
    for i in range(taille2):
        lettre = texte[i]
        Listeindices.append(i) = dico[lettre]
        Indices[i] = random.choice(Listeindices[i])
    return Indices
```

There are a number of problems with this code. The first is that the `list.append` method returns `None`, so the statement

```
Listeindices.append(i) = dico[lettre]
```

is equivalent to

```
None = dico[lettre]
```

which should be guaranteed to raise a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` exception.

Secondly your method of iterating over the numbered characters of a sequence could be much more efficiently achieved using

```
for i, lettre in enumerate(texte):
```

allowing you to eliminate the assignment to `taille2` before the loop and to `lettre` within it.

The most serious issue, though, is the statement

```
Indices[i] = random.choice(Listeindices[i])
```

`Indices` starts out as an empty list, and you never append anything to it, which guarantees that any attempt to access it with an index will fail with an `IndexError`, as you can see in an interpreter session:

```
>>> [][0] = "x"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

If you were to offer an explanation of what the code is actually supposed to achieve people might be able to offer more help. You should also quote the error traceback you receive, to locate the exact point of failure.